# Positioning icons

Tags: css, positioning

Since I'm complete new to this, I'll try to be as clear as possible.
My questions concerns the positioning of my buttonicons for my mobile pages.
Basically, for every page there is an option to select an icon which gets displayed to the left of the page title.

How would I change the positioning below in order to get the icons displayed on the right side of the page titles. Unfortunately I can't post a screenshot of the current and ideal situation. Ideally I would like to have the page titles slightly more to the left. 
I hope this still makes sense without a screenshot.

```
if($page->buttonicon){
    $icon = "<img src=\"icons/".$page->buttonicon."\" style=\"position:relative;    top:33px\">";
}
else{
    $icon = "<img src=\"images/noicon.png\" style=\"position:relative; top:33px\">";
}

$menurow = "<li id=row_".$page->id." style=\"display:$rstyle\">$icon<a class=\"".$bs."\" href=\"".trim($page->url)."\" $target >".$page->title."</a></li>\n";
```

If I may say, referring me to another post doesn't help me a lot since I'm completely new to this, so in order to avoid getting confused - I need this particular code to be used/rewritten.. :)

Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

The CSS stylesheet doesn't seem to affect the positioning. The CSS stylesheet only seems to be called for the layout of the navigation buttons. The icons within the navigation buttons are related to the first code mentioned above.

Comment: I suppose a screenshot wouldnt be bad, because i dont rly know what you mean with "Icons". Do you mean Favicons in the single tabs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just small buttonicons. If you would search for "mobile website" in google images - you would see that most mobile websites include a small icon for every navigation button. I need more reputation in order to be able to post a picture. :)

Comment: Hum, for this reason, you dont need php or JS, CSS gives you all the tools you need. Example is posted by Rossco below already.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can float HTML elements example:

```
float:left
float:right
```

If that doesnt work try setting the position of the element to absolute and physically margining the element into place:

```
position:absolute;
margin: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px
```

Comment: Tried the above. Looks like the CSS doesn't really affect the positioning. The only thing which seems to effect positioning is when I change the code mentioned in my post above. However, until now without any luck and only messing up its positoning. I tried your suggestion as well by leaving the code unchanged and changing the CSS to:                          #icon1 {
 position:absolute;
 width:44px;
 height:21px;
 z-index:1;
        margin: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px
}

Comment: and you have given the img tag a ID of icon1? And removed the styles within the img tag as inline styles overwrite any other styles applied to that element. And my mistake: use "margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px. The commas should not be there. Alternatively you can use margin-left margin-top so on.

Comment: Thanks again. I tested the #icon and I don't think this bit of CSS infuences the icons' positioning. Can't find an ID linking the icons'positioning. Even when deleting this bit of code, the icons are still displayed. In other words, an icon is selected from a dropdown menu but is not influenced by CSS. CSS is only for the layout of the navigation buttons. The icons within the navigation buttons are related to the first code mentioned above in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this inserts the image:

```
if($page->buttonicon){
    $icon = "buttonicon."\" style=\"position:relative;    top:33px\">";
    }
    else{
    $icon = "";
    }
```

and this inserts the title:

```
$menurow = "id." style=\"display:$rstyle\">$iconurl)."\" $target >".$page->title."\n";
```

If no CSS interferes, you should be able to simply switch the order of those two statements to get the desired effect.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks. Something like the code below? I tried (without any luck):

```
if($page->buttonicon){
$menurow = "<li id=row_".$page->id." style=\"display:$rstyle\">$icon<a class=\"".$bs."\" href=\"".trim($page->url)."\" $target >".$page->title."</a></li>\n";

$icon = "<img src=\"icons/".$page->buttonicon."\" style=\"position:relative; top:33px\">";
}
else{
$icon = "<img src=\"images/noicon.png\" style=\"position:relative; top:33px\">";
}
```